# int pointer to two struct pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is from the linux build files `<linux/usb/serial.h>`:

```
int (*calc_num_ports)(struct usb_serial *serial, struct usb_serial_endpoints *epds);
```

I'm just having a little trouble understanding what's going on here. An int pointer to two struct pointers? How does that work?

Comment: A pointer to a function taking two struct pointers and returning int. Learn how C declarations work.

Answer (score 0):

It tells you what it is and what it's used for in the header (`<linux/usb/serial.h>`):

```
@calc_num_ports: pointer to a function to determine how many ports this
 *  device has dynamically. It can also be used to verify the number of
 *  endpoints or to modify the port-endpoint mapping. It will be called
 *  after the probe() callback is called, but before attach().
```

The syntax for a function pointer is not very intuitive.  Consider the following:

```
int *calc_num_ports(struct usb_serial *serial, struct usb_serial_endpoints *epds);
int (*calc_num_ports)(struct usb_serial *serial, struct usb_serial_endpoints *epds);
```

The first is the prototype of a function named `calc_num_ports` that takes two arguments, `struct usb_serial *` and `struct usb_serial_endpoints *`, and `return`s an `int *`.

The second is a variable type that requires the address of a function that takes two arguments, `struct usb_serial *` and `struct usb_serial_endpoints *` and `return`s an `int`.